# Function after animation (image sequence)

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, uiimage

I've searched everywhere but I did not find a proper solution for my problem. I have a image-sequence playing on start up. After this sequence I want to trigger a function. A function that activates an Image which. So the animation will run fluently into the image without break. I found a lot of solutions on the internet e.g. doing it with a timer but running the code via simulator it works, on device it doesn't and gets delayed :(. Is it a good way to set the timer just by testing when the animation is finished? The method "animationDone" is always triggered on the wrong time!

Here my example code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00000.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00001.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00002.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00003.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00004.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00005.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00006.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00007.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00008.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00009.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00010.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00011.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00012.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00013.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00014.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00015.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00016.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00017.png"],nil];

    [imageView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
    [imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    [imageView startAnimating];

    [self performSelector:@selector(animationDone) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.2];
}
```

Comment: If your animation is `0.7` seconds long, and repeats once, the delay should be `1.4`, not `1.2`.

Comment: thanks! but why? :D is it a good way to do so?

Comment: @Austin `setAnimationRepeatCount:1` means it will do the animation only once (not that it will do it once and then repeat one more time).

Comment: @tyler By the way, unrelated to your original question, I'd be wary about using `imageNamed` to load a lot of images that will be used only once for an animation, because the images will be cached. For a one-time animation, I would use `imageWithContentsOfFile` (and make sure to `nil` the `animationImages` array when the animation is done).

Comment: @Rob Ah, then the delay should be `0.7`, instead of `1.2`, assuming op wants it to be called right at the end of the animation.

Comment: @Austin Yep, that's the easiest solution. I inferred from your question that you must have tried that and were unhappy with the results, which is why I suggested the display link approach, but I'd start with just using the same time interval for both the animation and the `afterDelay` parameter.

Comment: the method with the afterdelay of Rob works fine! on device and simulator, but there´s a little break in between so the images dont blend perfectly into each other! Whats the reason?

Comment: @tyler One of two possibilities: First (and less likely), your images might be too different from each other, resulting in a jarring transition as you go from frame to frame. Second, you could be doing something completely separate in your app which is blocking the main queue (e.g. a synchronous network request; retrieving another array of images; etc.), which would interfere with the animation. Make sure you don't perform any slow/synchronous operations on the main queue. Always do slow operations on a background queue to ensure you never block the main queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should try using the same interval for both the `afterDelay` parameter to `performSelector` and the `setAnimationDuration` (e.g., 0.7 seconds for both).

If that doesn't quite do what you want, you can programmatically call timer, constantly checking to see if the animation is done. For example, you could set up a display link (it's like a timer, but linked to updates to the display), and check `imageView.isAnimating`, e.g.:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageView.animationImages = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00000.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00001.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00002.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00003.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00004.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00005.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00006.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00007.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00008.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00009.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00010.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00011.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00012.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00013.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00014.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00015.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00016.png"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Rad_start_00017.png"]];

    [self.imageView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
    [self.imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];

    [self.imageView startAnimating];
    [self startDisplayLink];
}

- (void)startDisplayLink
{
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)stopDisplayLink
{
    [self.displayLink invalidate];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}

- (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    if (!self.imageView.isAnimating) {
        [self stopDisplayLink];

        NSLog(@"done");

        // do whatever else you want here
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: works fine! on device and simulator, but there´s a little break in between so the images dont blend perfectly into each other! Whats the reason?

Answer (score 0):

try using the delegate of the animation
and the setAnimationDidStopSelector:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationDelegate:

Comment: ok, thank you! Im pretty new to that stuff. How would it look like in code? Thanks!